# Vue-Firebase: How to connect to 2 firebases from the same app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I have two firebases on the same project and i need to connect to both of them.

There are two javascript files connecting to each firebase which seems ok.

I import both of them

```
  import db from '../FireBase'
  import mdb from '../MissionFireBase'

  let MissionRef = mdb.ref('mission');
  let TeamRef = db.ref('Teams');
  let StartRef = db.ref('start');
```

db is an export of one firebase and mdb of another. On itself each one of them works but when i try to use both of them i get an error

```
index.cjs.js?3b8b:360 Uncaught FirebaseError {code: "app/duplicate-app", message: "Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).", name: "[DEFAULT]", stack: "[DEFAULT]: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]…0)↵    at fn (http://localhost:8080/app.js:89:20)"}
```

To me it seems somewhere firebase gets a default id and when trying to use them both it conflicts. I tried calling each one from a different vue component but i get the same result.

The firebase connection is made like so

```
import Firebases from 'firebase'

let config = {

  apiKey: "--",
  authDomain: "--",
  databaseURL: "--",
  projectId: "--",
  storageBucket: "--",
  messagingSenderId: "--"

};

let apps= Firebases.initializeApp(config);
let mdb = apps.database();

export default mdb
```

Is this possible? Can i use two different firebase calls or would i need to merge them both together?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's definitely possible. You will need to create separate `FirebaseApp` instances for each, and then get your database from that.

```
var secondaryAppConfig = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
};
// Initialize another app with a different config
var secondary = firebase.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig, "secondary");

// Retrieve the database.
var secondaryDatabase = secondary.database();
```

For more on this, have a look at the section [using multiple projects in your application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application) in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: Ok i see what my problem is, when not giving a name it goes to [DEFAULT] which i had two of, so by giving them names i can hold as many as i want. Thanks!